# Java Browse a queue of object

Tags: java, queue

I have a queue of object, and I want to go through the queue and be able to use these objects.

I have this :

```
private String format(Queue<MyObject> queue) {

     for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
      //Here i would like to use "MyObject"
     }

}
```

I don't know if I'm wrong but I couldn't find out a good way to do it.
Thanks for helping,

Comment: Do you mean browsing the queue without actually removing any elements?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use all data from queue, format it, and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depending on the actual Queue implementation, you may be able to use an Iterator.

For example, for `PriorityQueue<E>` :

```
 * <p>This class and its iterator implement all of the
 * <em>optional</em> methods of the {@link Collection} and {@link
 * Iterator} interfaces.  The Iterator provided in method {@link
 * #iterator()} is <em>not</em> guaranteed to traverse the elements of
 * the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered
 * traversal, consider using {@code Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())}.
```

This means that the enhanced for loop would work :

```
for (MyObject obj : queue) {

}
```

However, not every Queue implementation is guaranteed to implement `iterator()`. You should check if the actual `Queue` implementation you are using supports iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` elements from the queue, if you do both of them exactly once at each iteration, it is guaranteed that the queue's size won't change, and when you are done - the queue will remain as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements in a list:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>(queue);
```

And iterate the list.